# Add a new property to a specific json node using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am exploring gson and wanted to check if I can remove and add elements. I have the below json

```
{
  "header": {
"timeStamp": "2016-02-09T15:22:36.107-08:00",
"uniqueid": "321ef660",
},
"body": {
"search": {
  "searchId": 9206422282,
      "DateFrom": "2016-04-15T00:00:00-07:00",
      "DateTo": "2016-06-24T00:00:00-07:00"
    }
  },
  "amount": [
    {   
        "amount": 73.704285,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "amountagain": {
        "amount": 96.791435,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "winners": null,
      "pgoodId": null,
      },
```

and now I want to add a new element under body like :

```
{
"header": {
"timeStamp": "2016-02-09T15:22:36.107-08:00",
"uniqueid": "321c5690-1d2e-4403-9c31-029cc47ef660",
},
"body": {
"search": {
  "searchId": 9206422282,
      "DateFrom": "2016-04-15T00:00:00-07:00",
      "DateTo": "2016-06-24T00:00:00-07:00"
      "AddANewFieldHere" : **"2016-04-18"**
    }
  }
```

when I do

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    try {
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/search.json"));
        jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException ioe){

    }

//    jsonObject.get("checkin");
jsonObject.addProperty("AddANewFieldHere","2016-04-18");
    System.out.print(jsonObject);

}
```

It adds this property at the end of the document not as I expect under body.

Comment: Seems that `jsonObject` is not the root object.

Comment: can you post the declaration of jsonObject

Comment: updated the code I am working with

Comment: Show the result please

Comment: Just to understand, what makes you expect that the code should place the new entry under "body" and not under the root?

Comment: Try to traverse inside the object you want and add the property there. jsonObject you mentioned points to the root element. Not the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonObject` is the root node. You need to navigate to the node you want to modify.

```
JsonObject body = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("body");
body.addProperty("AddANewFieldHere","2016-04-18");
```

From the example output, it looks like want it under the path `body/search/searchId` not `body` though:

```
JsonObject searchId = jsonObject
                .getAsJsonObject("body")
                .getAsJsonObject("search")
                .getAsJsonObject("searchId");
searchId.addProperty("AddANewFieldHere","2016-04-18");
```